# Can I change position of draw based on orientation of device

Tags: ios, swift, uidevice, uideviceorientation

I am trying to create a very basic iOS app using swift 2.0.I have a background image that I would like to draw on top of, but I want the drawing to look consistent in landscape and portrait mode. Using auto layout and constraints would be impossible because the image and its height to width ratio resize whenever the orientation is changed. I'm wondering if I could set some sort of offset from the edge of the page in the vertical and horizontal directions based on the orientation of the device. I have been trying to code it up but have been having trouble. I looked into using UIDeviceOrientation but am not sure how exactly to implement it in code. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to do this off the top of my head.. I haven't tried coding it yet however.

1. set an outlet to the two constraints that's set's the x and y of what you draw on top of the background. Then on the device orientation change you can just change the constraint.constant to a new value that fits better.
2. You can use the interface builders built in functionality to set constraint based on which sized screen you are dealing with.. You find it at the bottom of the interface builder main view... default values are "w: Any, h: Any"

Comment: how do you know the default device orientation or the one that it is on when the app launches

Comment: It's been a while since I played with orientation changed but you can get the current screen bounds and set the constraints based on that, no?
'UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds'

Comment: I don't know. Im very new to iOS. still trying to learn methods. swift class structure is a little confusing to me

Comment: I really think the second option in my answer is the better one though because then iOS will give you that functionality out of the box and you don't have to do anything in code

Answer (score 0):

Animal's second idea is great. You can try it [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)